# Server Path Performance (absolute vs relative links)

Tags: html, image, performance, linker

I've found numerous entries on here discussing this concept but none have actually provided legitimate / concrete evidence to support their claims that one is actually better in terms of performance. People talk about absolute paths requiring an extra DNS request, yet from the client (browser) perspective when calling a relative link the browser still converts it to an absolute link to make the call (to the best of my knowledge).

You can view this here (note: the following is NOT my site, but is used to demonstrate this purpose as it has the information necessary and I was able to acquire via the owner the log entries you find below):

http://heyjosh.net/lw/pathtest.html

```
10.20.7.143 - - [10/Oct/2013:10:37:59 -0400] "GET /lw/pathtest.html HTTP/1.1" 200 248 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36"

10.20.7.143 - - [10/Oct/2013:10:37:59 -0400] "GET /lw/prop-service.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 8777 "http://heyjosh.net/lw/pathtest.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36"

10.20.7.143 - - [10/Oct/2013:10:37:59 -0400] "GET /lw/prop-support.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 7540 "http://heyjosh.net/lw/pathtest.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36"
```

Can anybody provide actual evidence that there is an extra GET request (thus a "longer" time to acquire the absolute path image vs the relative path image? The following site:

http://www.boogiejack.com/server_paths.html

Flat out says the browser has to make an outbound call with absolute paths whereas the relative path it just "knows" it's on your server. That seems far fetched, but again: I'm looking for concrete proof / evidence.

Answer (score 1):

That is completely wrong.
There is no network-level performance difference between absolute and relative URLs.

In fact, the browser will *never* send a second DNS request for the same domain on the same page, to prevent DNS-level attackers from bypassing the same-origin policy.

Obviously, if the absolute URL is on a different domain, there will be a second DNS request.

Comment: Can you provide documentation supporting that regarding the browser? (it's not that I distrust your response, I'm just looking for legitimate, concrete evidence that I can use)